# how can i use uipagecontrol for a page with actions?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7, uipagecontrol

I want to create a page where the user can enter his/her details and then swipe through the next couple of pages which will be tutorial screens. I want the page controller to be present through the tutorial part and the part where the user enters their details. Almost all the tutorials I found used images and page control in conjunction.

Initially i thought that i could do this using uipageview controller, but then i realized that you can only put in images for tutorials!? Correct me if I'm wrong.
So now I'm considering using a scroll view with page control, but I'm not entirely sure about how to go about doing this.

Could somebody shed some light on how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. From UIPageViewController reference guide:

> A page view controller lets the user navigate between pages of
>   content, where each page is managed by its own view controller object.

Create a UIViewController with the login UI and logic then add it to the UIPageViewController.